Catching unbound named placeholders in QtSQL with PostgreSQL
I am using PyQt5 and a PostgreSQL database.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values
If I use positional placeholders in my query and not bind values to them, query execution will fail:
query.prepare("INSERT INTO t (id) VALUES (?);")
# missing bind values here
query.exec()
print(query.lastError().text())

->
ERROR:  wrong number of parameters for prepared statement "qpsqlpstmt_1"
DETAIL:  Expected 1 parameters but got 0.
(42601) QPSQL: Unable to create query

This is good as it catches mistakes.
I want to use named placeholders though.
If I use named placeholders in my query and not bind values to them, query execution will not fail. Instead a NULL value will be used.
query.prepare("INSERT INTO t (id) VALUES (:foo);")
# missing bind values here
query.exec()




id




NULL



I do not want that. I want to be able to catch such a misprepared query and tell the user.
How can I know if my query was set up properly, with a value bounded for each of its named placeholders?

Bound values work like a dictionary, meaning that their "keys" revert to "null" values: fundamentally, all keys are "unset", but they are still technically valid. Using QSqlQuery.boundValues() you get that mapping, with all keys initialized to None, but that could still be a valid record field (eg: NULL). Are those lines interpreted from user input? If so, I believe that the only option is to check if the query has bound values, and then ensure that all its keys are set with bindValue().

Ouch, that is disheartening to hear. Yes, the values come from user input. I would like to write good functions (basically taking the query string with named parameters and accompanying values) that other developers using my API can safely use. But like this, they would need to 100% check that they pass all values-to-be-bound to my functions. I was hoping that QtSql would have a way to determine which values were actually bound so I could raise an error.

Oh, I can simply compare the names passed to me with the names of the boundValues. I'll implement and test that, then post as answer if successful.

Named parameters are actually much easier to deal with, because all the information is available before executing the query. For positional parameters, you have to rely on the database providing a useful error - which is definitely not always the case (e.g. sqlite).

@bugmenot123 Well, that's the price of allowing and accepting user input: it's fundamentally unreliable to begin with. Still, consider that you can never provide a 100% certainty: if the user (or dev) is dumb or malicious (or both), there's little you could do. Providing a flexible API is perfectly fine, but there are limits. Document them: if people is that dumb/malicious/etc, then that's their fault, not yours.

query.boundValues() is a dictionary of the placeholders/parameters, all None before you actually bind values. E.g.: {":parameter1": None, ":parameter2": None, ...}
My API users now have to pass a dictionary of the same structure with their wanted values, e.g.: {":parameter1": 42, ":parameter2": None, ...}
The binding is done in a function of my API and it checks for matching parameters between the query's placeholders and the passed data using set comparisons:
missing_values = set(query.boundValues().keys()).difference(values_to_bind.keys())
if missing_values:
    raise ValueError(f"Missing input for named placeholder(s): {missing_values}")
missing_placeholders = set(values_to_bind.keys()).difference(query.boundValues().keys())
if missing_placeholders:
    raise ValueError(f"Missing placeholder(s) for passed value(s): {missing_placeholders}")

This way I can be sure that there is a 100% match between the named placeholders in the query and the actually bound values.
